# Computer freezes with Win 8 CP

Tags: windows-8-preview

I am using Windows 8 consumer preview on my HP model number HPE-510t.  I am having frequent computer freezes which required a complete reboot.  I turned off the optimization, but the problem persists.  Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 is still in preview mode as such, there are bound to be freezes. The frequent, random freezes however [seems](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/broken-windows-issues-windows-8-release-preview-unusable-143515) to be a [known](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1081347-annoying-freezing-issue/) issue & [has been fixed](http://techie-buzz.com/microsoft/microsoft-fixes-windows-8-freezing-bug.html).

Till then [this workaround](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/google-chrome-causes-my-computer-to-hang-up-and/a0903d3e-b2e3-4286-95e6-8d6f16631c1d) might help.

> Unfortunately this is a known issue, but I have a workaround that may
>   help you. Please note that this workaround could potentially increase
>   battery usage, and should be removed once a fix is available.
>
> From an elevated cmd prompt run
>
> ```
> bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes
> ```
>
> and reboot.